# match only HTML name regex

Tags: regex

I have this example :

```
<button type="sasasasasa" abcd="dsqdsq" efgh="sasasa">
```

I only want to match `"button"` `"type"` `"abcd"` and `"efgh"`.

I already tried : `[a-zA-Z:_][a-zA-Z:_.*]*` but it matches also what's inside the quotes `""`

I thought about taking either `"="` or `"<"` or `" "` at the beginning to only match but I don't want to have such caracters in my results.

Comment: Use an HTML parser _if you can_ because [Regex is not a good tool for matching HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/4934172).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
(?<= |<)[a-zA-Z]*(?==| )
```

How it works:

- `[a-zA-Z]*`: search for any sequence of letters which ...
- `(?<= |<)`: is preceded by either a `<` (as in the case of `button`) or by a space and ...
- `(?==| )`: is followed by either a `=` sign or a space (as in the case of `button`)

See it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4sJQwo/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
(?<=<|\s)[a-zA-Z:_][a-zA-Z:_.*][^=|\s]+
```

This will look after "<" or " " and before "=" or " " but will not include any of the characters.

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/CvrJDp/1) regex online tester.

Hope this helps